# Help required recovering old wallet

Tags: wallets

I bought some ETH back in 2018.  I kept it in a wallet app on my Mac then I forgot about it.  I have changed my Mac since then.

I think the app was just called Ethereum Wallet.  I recorded a key that looks like this:

154f61a5-dc90-8193-1123-94e22718d67b (not the actual key)

How can I recover my ETH?

Comment: That looks like a UUID, not a Ethereum private key. Ethereum Wallet used keystore (`UTC-date-address.json`) files IIRC. Maybe you have a Blockchain.com Wallet account? They use UUIDs as the Wallet ID.

Comment: Thanks @Morten.  Do you know where I could get a copy of that wallet these days?  The application I mean?

Comment: As far as I know they don't have an application, but you can log in through their website.